# TimeEvaluator for SmtpAppender in log4net doesn't work for web project

Tags: asp.net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have an ASP.NET web app that uses log4net to log to various appenders.  I have successfully added a `SmtpAppender` with a [`LevelEvaluator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator.html) and can get e-mails to be sent with this; however if I replace this with a [`TimeEvaluator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.TimeEvaluator.html) I cannot get e-mails to send.

My appender with the `LevelEvaluator` looks like this (this is working):

```
<appender name="EmailErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    <to value="to@myemail" />
    <from value="from@myemail" />
    <subject value="Alert Subject" />
    <smtpHost value="mymailhost" />
    <bufferSize value="50" />
    <lossy value="true" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ERROR"/>
    </evaluator>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

The problematic appender with the `TimeEvaluator` looks like this (**this is not working**):

```
<appender name="EmailErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    <to value="to@myemail" />
    <from value="from@myemail" />
    <subject value="Alert Subject" />
    <smtpHost value="mymailhost" />
    <bufferSize value="50" />
    <lossy value="true" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.TimeEvaluator">
        <interval value="30"/>
    </evaluator>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I've checked log4net's internal debug and it says it is loading it fine.

I would appreciate any help - is `TimeEvaluator` broken in an ASP.NET web context?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Are you sure that what you are seeing is not the expected behavior? TimeEvaluator will let an event pass only at most every <interval> seconds. You have no log event at all? If you also log to a file, does it log anything?

Comment: @samy - I've got a custom fallback appender (logs to SQL and then file if SQL fails) at the root level alongside the `SmtpAppender`.  This is working fine - so if I log an Error event I see it in the DB, but don't get an e-mail when using the `TimeEvaluator`.  As mentioned with the `LevelEvaluator` it's fine.

I was wondering if the time constraint is something that doesn't play well with the ASP.NET site.

Comment: It's worth saying that the class we use to log is a bespoke generic class (it was designed to be able to consume different logging libraries).  It is instantiated at an application level, and in this case it ultimately has a private property for the instance of the log4net class - this private property is instantiated when the parent class is instantiated and does not change, so I **don't** believe that the log object is being re-initialised with every web page call - it persists at an Application level